# Why can't I process twitter search api responses php

Tags: php, json, twitter

Hello I am attempting to connect to twitter to read statuses.
I can post them just fine.

I am stuck because The response that I am recieving is not json but a php object.

i am using the codebird library for the connection

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey($key, $secret);
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

    $cb->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);

    $reply = $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
```

The data that I get is not JSON like I expect it to be. It is instead an object

```
var_dump($reply);
```

gives

```
object(stdClass)#383 (22) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (26) { ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Fri Jan 08 16:36:03 +0000 2016" ["id"]=> string(18) "685500222852710401" ["id_str"]=> string(18) "685500222852710401" ["text"]=> string(142) "Check out the views from up here! Francesco Di Tommaso looks like he knows the best place for a good photo – sa...
```

and

```
json_decode($reply);
```

gives

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,
```

I used twitter api before in both python and c# but never encountered anything like this.

EDIT
The documentation says to cast to array the result of which is

```
array(22) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (26) { ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Fri Jan 08 17:20:00 +0000 2016" ["id"]=> string(18) "685511281630035968" ["id_str"]=> string(18) "685511281630035968" ["text"]=> string(129) "RT @ColumbiaRecords: We've got that #FridayFeeling listening to @wet's new track #AllTheWays on @Spotify! https://t.co/zLTCUJZ03X" ["source"]=> string(83) "TweetDeck" ["truncated"]=> bool(false) ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=> NULL ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=> NULL ["user"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (41) { ["id"]=> int(34442404) ["id_str"]=> string(8) "34442404" ["name"]=> string(4) "Sony" ["screen_name"]=> string(4) "Sony" ["location"]=> string(12) "New York, NY" ["description"]=> string(59) "The official Twitter account for Sony in the United States."...
```

Which I am still unable to convert to Json.

If my question sounds silly please Forgive me I am very new to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codebird is returning a php object, not a json string. Specifically relevant to your case, the [Codebird documentation](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) says, in its Return formats section:

> The default return format for API calls is a PHP object. For API methods returning multiple data (like statuses/home_timeline), you should cast the reply to array, like this:
>
> ```
> $reply = $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
> $data = (array) $reply;
> ```

Comment: I tried that but I don't know what to do with it either. I am really new to php I'll edit the question to include that. I can't convert that array to Json either.

Comment: `json_decode()` converts *from* json to a php value. Codebird is already giving you php values. There is nothing you need to decode. If you want to convert *to* json, then you need to use `json_encode()`.